# There is very slight difference but also statistically significant. Could there be a mistake?

Tags: p-value, paired-data, wilcoxon-signed-rank

In my study to investigate the effect of filter glasses on reading speed and contrast senstivity in albino patients, there is little change in the reading performance level
n:61 patients
Reading acuity "without filter": 0.75 ± 0.11 (1.05 - 0.50) and "with filter"   : 0.77 ± 0.11 (1.00 - 0.50)
Contrast sensitivity "without filter": 1.56 ± 0.20 (0.95 - 2.00) and  "with filter"   : 1.63 ± 0.20 (1.10 - 2.05)

, but it is statistically significant both. (p<0.001, Wilcoxon test)
One of the referees criticizes this issue as follows;
"Problem with the data. When standard deviation errors bars overlap quite a bit, it's a clue that the difference is not statistically significant.
a significant difference was shown for contrast sensitivity (1.56±0.20 vs 1.6±0.20 logCS; p<0.01).
An assessment of reading performance criteria revealed that RA (0.77±0.11 vs 0.75±0.11; p<0.01) was significantly improved by yellow filter application

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Is the ± value the standard deviation, or the standard error?

Comment: Standard deviation

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify in the text if the ± values are standard deviations ($\sigma$) or standard errors  ($\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$, where $n$ is the sample size).

The reviewer is treating them as standard errors. The rule of thumb is that if the means differ by more than two standard errors, the difference is significant, so the results wouldn't be significant if these were in fact the standard errors.

The solution is to explicitly state that these are standard deviations, and ideally also report the standard errors as well.

Comment: To add: actually, this rule of thumb is plain wrong. (e.g. Austin and Hooks, 2002. "A brief note on overlapping confidence intervals", J Vasc Surg)

Comment: Agreed, but it's clearly what the reviewer is doing.

Comment: To be pedantic, that paper is about whether the two 95% CIs overlap. That's different from testing whether one mean is within the 95% CI/two SEs of the other.

Comment: @ LuckyPal @ Eoin is on the job market, I am aware that it is not appropriate to analyze without a statistician, but as the last question, how should I answer the referee?

Comment: I've already answered that. Clarify that the ± values are standard deviations, not standard errors as the reviewer seems to think, and ideally report both.